# Bootstrap Vue - Prevent dropdown close on click outside

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Bootstrap-Vue and I would like my dropdown to never hide until a button calls a function. My issue is that, by default, clicking outside the dropdown or on the dropdown button hide the dropdown. My template is:

```html
    <b-dropdown
      ref="dropdown"
      @hide="onEditControlMenuHide"
      @click.native.stop>
      <b-dropdown-form>
        <b-dropdown-item-button
          @click="closeDropdown"
          >I'm a button
        </b-dropdown-item-button>
      </b-dropdown-form>
    </b-dropdown>
```

And then I have simple methods in my script:

```js
    closeDropdown() {
      this.$refs.dropdown.hide()
    },

    onEditControlMenuHide(bvEvent) {
      bvEvent.preventDefault()
    },
```

I tried to catch the `bvEvent` in a function to process where the event comes from, but I find nothing in the event that differentiate hide on click outside, hide on click the dropdown button, or hide because on my custom button.
I read that it was maybe because of event bubbling, so I tried to use `@click.native.stop` but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a flag that is only set to true by the button's `click`-handler, then the `hide`-handler would only cancel the hide if the flag is set:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    closeDropdown() {
      this._okToHide = true
      this.$refs.dropdown.hide()
    },

    onEditControlMenuHide(bvEvent) {
      if (this._okToHide) {
        this._okToHide = false
      } else {
        bvEvent.preventDefault()
      }
    },
  }
})
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zYNpQNq?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <b-dropdown-item-button
      @click.stop="closeDropdown"
      >I'm a button
    </b-dropdown-item-button>
```

try to use .stop modificator with click event on ur button and not on dropdown, it stops propagination event from button and should not trigger click event on dropdown.